# How to fetch a table from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie to PHP and I'm just trying the very basics of MVC. Everything is going good but I have a problem while fetching data from MySQL and populating a HTML table with it.

The problem is that my code is just returning one row of the table (there are three rows in that table).
I have tried many things and right now I'm using arrays for storing the data and passing to controller and then to the view.

Query class file having a function for getting data and name `queryDB`:

```
 public function getdata(){
    $connectObj=new dbConnection(); 
    //its a connection class where mysql connection has been made
    if(!$connectObj->connectDB()){
        echo "Error in mysql: ".mysql_error();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $query = "select * from tbl_cartypes";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

        $data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[0] = $row['car_id'];
            $data[1] = $row['car_name'];
            $data[2] = $row['car_model'];
            $data[3] = $row['car_type'];
            $data[4] = $row['car_price'];

        }
          return $data;

    }
     $connectObj->closeDB();
}
```

The controller class where the controller of this query is name `carController.php`:

```
public function getAllData(){
    $runQuery = new queryDB();
    $array = array();
    $array = $runQuery->getTickets($userid);
    return $array;
}
```

And the final view where I'm just echoing my data:

```
include "$path/controllers/carController.php";

$ticket = new carController();
$array = array();
$array = $ticket->getdata();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        echo $array[$i]."<br />";
}
```

Output of this code is without error, but the problem is that it's just fetching one row of the table whereas there are three rows.

So any one can help me with this?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php OR http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: oh ok .. i'll try to learn that..thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's fetching all rows, but you're saving all the data to the same place (`$data[0]` through `$data[5]`), so all but the last row is getting overwritten.

This might work better:

```
 $data = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $data[] = $row;
 }
```

Comment: nope .. i have tried this before but the output which was showing on the page was just "Array"

Comment: @user1602152 that is because you are trying to echo an array, which can't be done in PHP. Please start with replacing your 'echo' with a 'print_r' command, the syntax is print_r($variableOrArray), so don´t forget the parenthesis. You will then see that the desired values are in your array. The individual values can be echoed like this: for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        echo $array[$i]['car_name']."<br />";
}

Comment: well its still giving me only one row .. i want all the rows in my view file thats the main problem im facing otherwise my code is doing the same as your code i.e fetching only first row from the table

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO and what other people have posted try using this

```
public function getdata(){
  $connectObj=new dbConnection(); 
  //its a connection class where mysql connection has been made
  if(!$connectObj->connectDB()){
      echo "Error in mysql: ".mysql_error();
      return false;
  }
  else{
  $query =  'select * from tbl_cartypes';
  $result = $connectObj->query($query);

  $data = array()

  foreach ($result as $row){
   array_push($data, $row)
  }

  return $data;

}
 $connectObj->closeDB();
```

}

Comment: nopes that did'nt work either ... im having this error on it **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're overwriting the values of the previous table:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[0] = $row['car_id'];
    $data[1] = $row['car_name'];
    $data[2] = $row['car_model'];
    $data[3] = $row['car_type'];
    $data[4] = $row['car_price'];
}
```

This will just re-write the last row of data over the key's in that table.

Try:

```
$data = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($data, $row)
}
```

Comment: its just giving me output as *Array*

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is assigning just one row to array $data. in while loop instead try this

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data["car_id"][] = $row['car_id'];
            $data["car_name"][] = $row['car_name'];
            $data["car_model"][] = $row['car_model'];
            $data["car_type"][] = $row['car_type'];
            $data["car_price"][] = $row['car_price'];

        }
  return $data;
```

Now you can iterate through the array.